# Grouping SCSS (Sass) Mixins

Tags: css, sass, mixins

converting some CSS to Sass, for example:

```
.ptn,
.pvn,
.pan{padding-top:0px !important}
```

to this

```
@mixin ptn {padding-top:0px !important}
@mixin pvn {padding-top:0px !important}
@mixin pan {padding-top:0px !important}
```

but wishing i could do something more like this

```
@mixin ptn,
@mixin pvn,
@mixin pan {padding-top:0px !important}
```

is something along these lines possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
@mixin nopadding{ padding-top:0px !important }

.ptn,
.pvn,
.pan{ @include nopadding }
```

?
Sass is about Reusability, so try to keep the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by breaking this up into a new mixin.

Additionally you could write something like this:

```
@mixin nopadding{ padding-top:0px !important }

@mixin anothermixin{ @include nopadding; ... }

normalselector{ @include anothermixin; }
```

Comment: brilliant. thanks for the insights re DRY and thanks for the tips on syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the `@extend` feature to be a little cleaner, depending on your purposes.

So if you have:

```
.ptn { padding-top:0px !important; }
```

You can do this anywhere else in your code (it doesn't require it to go after for scoping purposes, like mixins do):

```
.pvn { @extend .ptn; /* pvn-specific rules can still go here */ }

.pan { @extend .ptn; /* pan-specific rules can still go here */}
```

This will output as such:

```
.ptn, .pvn, .pan { padding-top:0px !important; }

.pvn { /* pvn-specific rules can still go here */ }

.pan { /* pan-specific rules can still go here */ }
```

This can be a cleaner output than using mixins, which would duplicate the code. This is particularly useful for larger blocks of code, like clear fixes. But mixins do have their place.

Speaking of things having their place… is that `!important` really necessary? ;-)